# Use multiple REGEXP_REPLACE calls in single column for MySQL 8 SELECT statement

Tags: mysql

#### Synopsis

I would like to use multiple `REGEXP_REPLACE` function calls in a `SELECT` statement. The idea is to replace different expressions with different values.

Using a single call to `REGEXP_REPLACE` works perfectly fine. Anyone with a first name that doesn't start with `T` is displayed as `NOT TREVOR`, and anyone who has a name starting with `T` is simply displayed as-is.

```
DROP DATABASE cbtnuggets;
CREATE DATABASE cbtnuggets;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cbtnuggets.people (firstName varchar(30));

INSERT INTO cbtnuggets.people (firstName) VALUES ('Trevor'), ('Daniel'), ('Sally');

SELECT 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(firstName, '^[^T].*', 'NOT TREVOR')
  FROM cbtnuggets.people;
```

#### Problematic Query

The following query does not work the way that I would like for it to. Due to the `OR` statement, the result is a 0 or 1, instead of a string.

```
DROP DATABASE cbtnuggets;
CREATE DATABASE cbtnuggets;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cbtnuggets.people (firstName varchar(30));

INSERT INTO cbtnuggets.people (firstName) VALUES ('Trevor'), ('Daniel'), ('Sally');

SELECT 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(firstName, '^[^T].*', 'NOT TREVOR')
  OR REGEXP_REPLACE(firstName, '^T', 'This is Trevor')
  FROM cbtnuggets.people;
```

#### Expected Result

I would like to return different values for different expressions in a single `SELECT` statement (if possible), using the `REGEXP_REPLACE` function.

#### Question

Is there any way to handle this desired result in a select statement, or would I need to create a MySQL function to handle these multiple expressions?

Comment: Your second `REGEXP_REPLACE()` will return `This is Trevorevor`. Did you intend the regexp to be `^T.*`?

Comment: Also, it will return `This is Trevor` if the name is `Thomas`. Seems like a strange result.

Comment: Oops, yes sorry I did intend it to return that string. This is just a theoretical example though!

Comment: And yes, I realize that `Thomas` or any other name starting with `T` will return that result. This is just an example, so it's not necessarily supposed to "make sense." But good catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run one regexp_replace(), which returns a string, and that string can be the input to another regexp_replace().

```
mysql> select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('Frank', '^T.*', 'This is Trevor'), '^[^T].*', 'This is not Trevor') as newlabel;
+--------------------+
| newlabel           |
+--------------------+
| This is not Trevor |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('Trevor', '^T.*', 'This is Trevor'), '^[^T].*', 'This is not Trevor') as newlabel;
+----------------+
| newlabel       |
+----------------+
| This is Trevor |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This usage works, but it's pretty confusing to write, especially if you have more than two patterns to check. I'd try to use a different approach.

Comment: Oh wow, this is a neat solution ... although yes, I agree it's pretty confusing code. However, this is probably the closest to what I was originally looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even sure you need regex here for your query:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN firstName LIKE 'T%'
         THEN 'This is Trevor'
         ELSE 'NOT TREVOR' END AS label
FROM cbtnuggets.people;
```

The `REGEXP_REPLACE` function is intended to take an input string and output a modification of that input, rather than a boolean value.  If you did want to assert a regex pattern against a string, then use `REGEXP`:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN firstName REGEXP '^T'
         THEN 'This is Trevor'
         ELSE 'NOT TREVOR' END AS label
FROM cbtnuggets.people;
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't need regex for this particular example. I am just trying to find out if there's a way to have multiple `REGEXP_REPLACE` calls in a single column. Using a `CASE` statement with `REGEXP` seems like a reasonable alternative.

Comment: I think the answer to my original question is "no" it's not possible to have multiple `REGEXP_REPLACE` references in a single column in a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: @Trevor It is hard for me to answer your comment above because, as my answer mentions, `REGEXP_REPLACE` doesn't return a boolean, it returns a string, and it doesn't make sense to `OR` together two such calls.

Comment: Yeah I realize that the `OR` doesn't make sense, but I was just trying to get my intentions across in the OP. Maybe I shouldn't have included that lame attempt in my post at all, as it seems to have confused my intent.

Comment: There are some languages where the logical OR operator returns the first successful result. SQL is not one of them, it always returns a boolean value.

Comment: I don't think it has an operator that works the way you want `OR` to work. `COALESCE()` does it for `NULL` testing.

Comment: Also, `REGEXP_REPLACE()` doesn't return an empty result when there's nothing to replace, it just returns the original string unchanged. So it wouldn't even work if `OR` did what you wanted.

Comment: It sounds to me like the "correct" way to handle this would be using an in-line `CASE` statement, as @TimBiegeleisen suggested, or wrapping the logic inside a MySQL function.